# Convert all .jpg images in directory to .pdf | Debugging ImageMagick

Tags: windows, image, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I have found multiple posts regarding this issue and everyone is recommending [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) but for me, it doesn't seem to work as intended and I don't see too many docs on their site regarding .jpg->.pdf conversion.

Is there some alternative, preferably CLI tool?

Or can I somehow debug why ImageMagick doesn't work for me? I don't get any errors I just get corrupted files as a result.

**My usecase**

---

My os is Windows and
I have 64 .jpg files called 0.jpg, 2.jpg, ... 63.jpg and I would like to merge all those images into one .pdf file.

I have tried these commands:

```
magick *.jpg out.pdf

convert *.jpg out.pdf
```

but in both cases, I am unable to open the out.pdf file because it is corrupted. I have noticed that I can only convert 0.jpg file to pdf correctly but when I try to convert any other of my 64 jpg files then as a result I am getting a corrupted .pdf file
For example:
This gives me the correct .pdf:

```
magick 0.jpg 0.pdf
```

but this gives me corrupted .pdf:

```
magick 2.jpg 2.pdf
```

I assume that this a reason why I can't merge all of the files into one not corrupted .pdf file and my assumption is that there is something wrong with the rest of my .jpg files but I have no idea how to debug this issue. Every other .jpg file looks exactly the same as the one .jpg I can convert and all of them open without issues.

***magick identify -verbose foobar.jpg* results:**

---

I can convert 0.jpg file to .pdf correctly but 2.jpg results in corrupted .pdf.
There are some apparent differences but I am not sure what those properties mean in the context of .jpg -> .pdf conversion

[image: magic identify -verbose]

Comment: What version of ImageMagick? How did you install it? Did you install the correct 32 or 64 bit version of ImageMagick for your platform? Where did you get your ImageMagick install?

Comment: @fmw42 **version:** `7.0.11-5-Q16-HDRI-x64`
**downloaded from here:** https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows **Direct download link:** https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.11-5-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe 
I have downloaded ready to run .exe which has install wizard and I have chosen 64bit on purpose

Comment: Try hex-dumping your *"happy"* JPEG (`0.jpg`) at this site https://hexed.it and check the first few bytes are a valid JPEG signature (`ff d8 ff`). Then check an *"unhappy"* JPEG the same way and see what you get.

Comment: Also, try `magick identify -verbose XXX.jpg` and look at the first few lines to see if they look the same for *"happy"* and *"unhappy"* JPEGs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated my question with results of `magick identify -verbose XXX.jpg` and there are some apparent differences but I am not sure how to interpret them. I have also tried hex-dumping and both files have correct JPEG signature (`ff d8 ff`)

Comment: Mmm... the main difference I can see is that the second is greyscale but I don't know why that would make any difference.

Comment: What tool are you using to view your PDF files?

Comment: @fmw42 google chrome or microsoft edge and also kindle.

Comment: It must be either a Windows based issue or a browser issue. I can do `magick 20.jpg 20.pdf` on my Mac OSX Sierra with IM 7.0.11.5 and open the pdf just fine in Chrome and Acrobat Reader and Mac Preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thought is that someone has converted the grayscale image to color with 3 equal channels so that it IM says it has colorspace RGB. However, the JPEG colorspace tag is 2, which says it has no specific colorspace.

```
Properties:
    date:create: 2021-04-01T17:29:06+00:00
    date:modify: 2021-04-01T05:18:58+00:00
    exif:ExifOffset: 46
    exif:ExifVersion: 48, 50, 50, 48
    exif:PixelXDimension: 960
    exif:PixelYDimension: 1508
    exif:Software: Google
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
```

From the JPG docs

ColorSpace

```
0 = Bi-level 
1 = YCbCr, ITU-R BT 709, video 
2 = No color space specified 
3 = YCbCr, ITU-R BT 601-1, RGB 
4 = YCbCr, ITU-R BT 601-1, video 
8 = Gray-scale 
9 = PhotoYCC 
10 = RGB 
11 = CMY 
12 = CMYK 
13 = YCCK 
14 = CIELab
```

It is possible that this conflict or lack of colorspace may confuse certain viewers after the file is imbedded in a PDF vector shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mark Setchell for pointing me in the right direction by sharing this command:

```
magick identify -verbose XXX.jpg
```

My images are grayish so I don't know why majority of the files has `sRGB` colorspace but after converting colorspace to `Gray` I can convert them to .pdf properly (I don't see any difference when I open up my .jpgs after conversion to grayscale).

Using this command I can change colorspace to `Gray`:

```
magick 2.jpg -colorspace gray gray2.jpg
```

Then I can convert "grayscale" .jpgs to .pdf by simply:

```
magick gray2.jpg gray2.pdf
```

---

P.S.
If anyone has some better solution I will gladly accept it but if nothing shows up I am going to accept this

@fmw42
Here is a [.zip file](http://sendanywhe.re/JY9D3STM) that contains

- 20.jpg - source image
- 20.pdf - corrupted pdf after running `>magick 20.jpg 20.pdf`
- gray20.jpg - source image converted to gray by `>magick 20.jpg -colorspace gray gray20.jpg`
- gray20.pdf - source image converted to .pdf after changing colorspace to gray first by `>magick gray20.jpg gray20.pdf`

Keep in mind that this image is from some weird manga but I have tried to pick the most normal page (it was harder than it seemed to be but this image itself is not nsfw)

Comment: Why do you have -evaluate-sequence mean when you only  have one input image?  Try `magick 2.jpg -colorspace gray gray2.jpg`

Comment: Can you post your gray2.jpg or any one that fails, so that I can test further or report to the ImageMagick team.

Comment: @fmw42 updated colorspace command and added a link to .zip file